# Run main in an Android Eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have some code that uses the android packages for HTML parsing.  Is there a simple way to run the code in Eclipse using a main method without fussing with an emulator?

Comment: I was hoping to run the code on the PC (no device)...

Comment: then you need dalvikvm executable for x86 , and you can run it. I guess you can download it from internet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really do want to run a main over your code (let's say, you got a routine to run): 
Create another Eclipse project referencing the Android code and put you main there. You'll be able to call any class that do not depend on an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it. I think its more complicated than the normal apk method. But you could still try it. You need dx tool. dx tool is present in android-sdk/platform-tools/

```
class Foo {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Hello, world"); 
 } 
}
```

javac Foo.java
 dx --dex --output=foo.jar Foo.class
 adb push foo.jar /sdcard
 adb shell dalvikvm -cp /sdcard/foo.jar Foo

you can get more information [here](http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/hello-world.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. When programming for Android, you can't use a "Main" method. Android applications begin in the `onCreate` method of your class that extends Activity.

EX: `public class LeGame extends Activity`

However, I assume you want to run your Android code without using the computer's emulator. You can run it on your Android phone. On your phone, go to Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging (Check it).

Now, when you connect your phone to your computer, you can simply click "Run" in eclipse, and your application will run on your phone.

(Assuming you have downloaded and installed all the required Android SDK packages, etc)